# twitter login integration in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, twitter-login

I am trying to integrate twitter login in my webapge. I am using react-twitter-auth for this.I am not understanding what I have to pass in place of loginurl and request token url. can you please let me know what I have to use in this place.

ex:

```js
<TwitterLogin loginUrl="http://localhost:4000/api/v1/auth/twitter"
              onFailure={this.onFailed}
              onSuccess={this.onSuccess}
              requestTokenUrl="http://localhost:4000/api/v1/auth/twitter/reverse"
              showIcon={true}
              customHeaders={customHeader}>
    <b>Custom</b> 
      Twitter 
    <i>Login</i> content
</TwitterLogin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a backend to validate the authentication of twitter. The following tutorial show's how the implementation is done.

[Twitter Implementation](https://medium.com/@robince885/how-to-do-twitter-authentication-with-react-and-restful-api-e525f30c62bb)

Comment: I have that backend to validate it. but after twitter login am calling the API to validate their i have to send some other parameters too. Am able to integrate with firebase.

Answer (score 0):

loginurl - URL that will be used to finish 3rd step of authentication process
and
request token url - URL that will be used to get request token

check this github repo -- https://github.com/alien35/social-auth-example
it helped me.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30535328)